# Why is left multiplication on a group bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I noticed the fact "left multiplication on a group is always bijective" is a very common argument (for instance to prove Sylow's theorem)

I don't see why left (and right) multiplication is bijective in general.
All I can see is that left multiplication is an action of a group on itself, so let $G$ be a group:
$$\cdot: G \times G \longrightarrow G$$
$$(g,g') \longmapsto g \cdot g'=gg'$$
Properties of group actions hold. I tried to prove this by contradiction but I'm not able to find any useful argument.
Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: When I hear "acting via left multiplication" on a group I think of taking a $g \in G$ and defining $\mu_g : G \rightarrow G$ by $\mu_g(g') = gg'$, which is a bijection from $G$ to $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $gx=gy$.  Then $g^{-1} gx=g^{-1} gy \implies x=y$.  That proves injectivity.

Suppose $g'\in G$.  Then $g (g^{-1}g')=g'$ implies surjectivity.

---

In addition, in terms of actions, left multiplication by an element of a group is *transitive* and *faithful*. These are somewhat similar notions.

Answer (score 7):

The map $\ell_g$ defined by $\ell_g(h)=gh$ is a bijection $G\to G$. Indeed, note that the map $\ell_{g^{-1}}=\ell_g^{-1}$ because
$$ (\ell_{g^{-1}}\circ\ell_g)(h)=g^{-1}gh=h$$
and similarly
$$ (\ell_g\circ \ell_{g^{-1}})(h)=gg^{-1}h=h.$$
The analogous argument shows that the right multiplication operator is a bijection. Note that none of these operators is a group homomorphism except for example $\ell_e=\Bbb{1}_G.$